# what is the correct header should pass in angular 8 formdata to upload excel file

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular8

When i am uploading a excel file , i found 0 value in Api HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count=0

But when I test in postman i am getting HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count>0

Please suggest proper solution so that i can upload excel file

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

uploadFile( event : any) {

```
let formData=new FormData();
formData.append("file",this.file,this.file.name);

let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data','enctype': 'multipart/form-data'});

this._http.post("http://localhost:58899/api/Accounts" ,formData, { headers }).subscribe(
  (data) => {
      // Success
      console.log(data);
  },
  (error) => {
      // error
      console.log(error);
  }
);
```

}